# how to auto login after successfully registered in laravel 5.4.12?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i want to make an auto login after successful registration and redirect to Edit Profile page.. I tried the following code but not working as i want

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/edit_profile';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

public function createUser(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request , [
        'firstName'    => 'required',
        'lastName'     => 'required',
        'displayName'  => 'required',
        'email'        => 'required |email',
        'password'     =>'required ',
        'gender'       =>'required',
        'day'          =>'required|max:2',
        'month'       =>'required|max:2',
        'year'       =>'required|max:4',
    ]);
    $email=$request->input('email');
    $password=$request->input('paasword');
    $dob=$request->input('day').'-'.$request->input('month').'-'.$request->input('year');
    $request->request->add(['dob'=>$dob]);
    $request->request->add(['password'=>bcrypt($request->input('password'))]);
    $data = User::create($request->except(['_token', 'submit', 'day','month','year', 'confirm_password' ,'dayInWeek']));

    Auth::login($data);

 }

}
```

**Routes**

```
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@login');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
    {
     Route::get('main', 'PageController@main');

     Route::get('browse', 'PageController@browse');

     Route::get('pickngo', 'PageController@pickngo');

     Route::get('edit_profile', 'PageController@profile');
    }
```

Comment: if you're using laravel's `make:auth`  try to set the active flag to true and test if this is the case. if so we'll start to figure out a solution depending on your business

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Laravel loginUsingId($id) function by passing the user id.

```
$data = User::create($request->except(['_token', 'submit', 'day','month','year', 'confirm_password' ,'dayInWeek']));

Auth::loginUsingId($data->id);
```

Comment: this saved my time, as i am making cutoms registration so it helped me for custom registartion. thanks

Answer (score 2):

just modify your auth login just like

```
if(Auth::login($data))   {
   return redirect('/edit_profile');
   }
   else
  {
   return redirect()->back();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Scren from documentation. 
You just need to add after login redirectTo property or method inside your LoginController.
P.S.it will work if you're using laravel's `make:auth`.
[image: Screen from documentation]